# How to set Deep-link for Oauth 2.0 in android app auth

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, deep-linking, appauth

I have to Implement OAuth 2.0 in my application and I am using AppAuth library for it. I have successfully implemented the authorisation, but facing issues with deep linking.

```xml
<activity android:name=".Activities.HybridRedirectReceiverActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="connect.example.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/oauthcallback" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This is how I set redirect receiver activity, and my target activity is set to `android:launchMode= "singleInstance"`.
My redirect Uri is `connect.example.com:/oauthcallback`.

When I use "host" instead of "pathPrefix" in manifest I can not return to my activity after login. But when using path prefix I am able to return to my activity after login but I can not retrieve my intent. It always return null. Does anyone know how I can use this redirect Uri `connect.example.com:/oauthcallback` with my manifest and retrieve intent after authorisation?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Android Studio
2. At the top, go to Tools
3. Select App Links Assistant
4. Follow the steps one by one carefully and you will be done.

** Note - You will need the help of back-end developer who will save your Digital Asset Links File (You will get in Step 3) in a path of your website like this - 
https://example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json

Comment: Actually I am using Microsoft identity server as authorisation server. will this method work with it? Because I want a general flow like app(auth request)=> login(on login button click) => back to app(using redirect uri )

Comment: Okay. what is the significance of firebase here?

Comment: I am really sorry.  Need not to worry about that.